# activemq start suppresses stdout/stderr

Tags: log4j, activemq-classic, java-service-wrapper

when using AMQ 5.6 and starting the broker using `./activemq start`...where does the stdout/stderr go?

I expected it to show up in the `/data/activemq.log` file, but it doesn't...is there are way around this with a tweak to the log4j or JavaServiceWrapper config perhaps?

When I start in console mode using `./activemq console`, the stdout/stderr messages are displayed as expected.  In particular, I need to get output from `e.printStackTrace()` to show up in the logs when running in this mode.

Comment: apparently the stderr/out is simply redirected to /dev/null based on startup script...strange that its not just sent to a log file by default

Answer (score 2):

it seems to just get redirected to /dev/null...I changed the `/bin/activemq` script to redirect to `../data/start.log` instead and sure enough, the stdout/err are there...not sure why this isn't the default behavior to be honest...

Answer (score 0):

When i remember correctly, there is another file  called wrapper.log. look out for it in the same dir where wrapper.conf is.